# Trying to find ASP.NET webcontrol in the style of PopupPanel (GWT)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gwt

I'm trying to find a ASP.NET webcontrol (maybe J.query) that mimics the behaviour of PopupPanel from GWT.
I want to create a panel in ASP.NET that overlaps a table then hides when clicking outside (or on mouse leave).

Thanks.

More info: I wanted to do something like the toolbox behaviour (Visual Studio), that stays over the editor when not pinned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list of popup plug-ins on the jQuery site:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/popup